# How would I globally add +1 to a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

There was a problem with an sql server and my voting system set back people 1 day.  I want to make it up to them and give them 1 point increase to make up for the loss.

How would I go about doing that? I was thinking of this but I don't think it would work..

```
SELECT votepoints FROM vsystem where votepoints=votepoints+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. What you are saying is like search where the result equals the result plus 1. That won't be true.

You can UPDATE your table:

```
update vsystem set votepoints = votepoints + 1
```

...or get the results + 1 (without modifying the table):

```
select (votepoints + 1) as voteplus from vsystem
```

Comment: Ohh I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot for pointing that out and making it clear. :)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE vsystem SET votepoints=votepoints+1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a one-time fix, just do:

```
UPDATE vsystem
SET votepoints = votepoints + 1
```

This will add 1 to the `votepoints` column for every row in the `vsystem` table.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE vsystem SET votepoints=votepoints+1;